# How to create a list in latex with titles in bold

Tags: lists

I provide an doctored image (don't have permission to share the content of the paper from which I took the snippet) of what I'm looking for, I have done some research on Google but couldn't seem to find what I am looking for.

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you look for a `description` list?

Comment: what you try so far? you could show this with some dummy text (for it you not need any permission :-) ).

Answer (score 2):

In case you want a custom *automatically enumerated* list, here's how to do it easily with `enumitem`, which uses a system of `key=...` to control the parameters of lists:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[11]

\begin{enumerate}[label=RQ\arabic*, font=\bfseries, wide=0pt, leftmargin=1.8em ]

\item Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.

\item Another text. Another text. Another text. Another text. Another text. Another text. Another text. Another text.

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As @TeXnician pointed out the solution to this is a `description`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}

\item[foo]
bar

\item[baz]

bang

\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for the help provided!